# Wrong cell is loading from the nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib, nib

I have this part of code:

```
+ (id) cell
{
    BaseXibCell * cell;
    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self xibName] ofType:@"nib"] != nil)
    {
        NSArray * nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [self xibName] owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex: [self nibIndex]];
        return cell;
    }
```

I need to load cell from the xib, so I have a nib with path:

```
...iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/53C938B7-55B0-4836-8840-B15146C2DF44/AxEmpExample.app/AxDynamicListRecordStyleCell.nib
```

but the `nibObjects` contains only one cell with absolutely wrong class:

```
Printing description of nibObjects:
AxDynamicListCell
```

the root cell object class in `AxDynamicListRecordStyleCell.xib` is set as `AxDynamicListRecordStyleCell`.

Can't understand the how to solve this.. Any help?

Comment: First of all: Use one xib for every view. And show the xib.

Comment: @dasdom to use one xib isn't possible - the xib is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ifk2we19p5fzw3w/Screenshot%202014-05-26%2022.02.08.png

Comment: What is [self xibName]; Can you show the code. And too by looking at your code it seems your code is loading `BaseXibCell` instead of `AxDynamicListRecordStyleCell`.

Comment: @iphonic [self xibName]; return NSStringFromClass([self class]); and BaseXibCell is the base class for my cells, all the cells in my question are the subclasses of this cell

Comment: @iphonic xibName is used in every subclass and it returns correct value of nib which I should get - I checked this via NSLog

Comment: what about [self nibIndex]; ? it should be 0 always..

Comment: @iphonic yes, it returns 0..

Comment: @ShurupuS can you change the owner from `self` to `nil`?

Comment: @iphonic mm, how can I do that?

Comment: NSArray * nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: [self xibName] owner:nil options:nil]; Check owner.

Comment: @iphonic the same result unfortunately (